# Can I add an Imgur image to my gallery without reuploading it?

Tags: imgur

Can I add an image uploaded to Imgur by someone else to my Imgur account without re-uploading it?

I like to keep a collection of images in my Imgur account that I find interesting, all of which show up at `http://<username>.imgur.com/all/`. However, it seems wasteful to use Imgur in order to rehost images that are already hosted on Imgur.

Answer (score 1):

The favourite button allows you to keep all favourited pictures in a "favourites" album. It is a small heart icon near the upvote and downvote buttons. The hotkey is numpad <kbd>0</kbd>.

Comment: When the owner of the image delete it, will it be still accessible to those who have already fav'ed it?